# Returning a struct by value vs by reference

Tags: c++

I want to return multiple values in C++ and I have this snippet of code:

```
struct returns
{  
   int row_locs, col_locs;  
   int row_descriptors, col_descriptors;  
   double **locs;  
   double **descriptors;  
};



void returns (int &row_locs, int &col_locs, int &row_descriptors, int &col_descriptors, double **locs, double **descriptors)
{  
   //make some changes in variables 
}
```

The question is "What consumes more time : `struct` or call by reference?"

Comment: Your code makes zero sense. `struct returns` and then a function `void returns` that doesn't actually return anything but there's just a stand-alone `return` statement?

Comment: Just time it yourself.  Create loops in which each operation is performed 100,000 times or something like that and time them.

Comment: @NikosC. What he's trying to do is clear.  What is important is the struct members.  Should he create a struct which contains them and return it by value?  Or pull them out and return them all by reference from the function that does the work?

Comment: Note that the function cannot "return" a `double **` value, because the parameter has type `double **` instead of `double **&`.

Comment: I haven't timed it, but my money is on the output parameters. Simply because they allow to save a copy.

Comment: I have tried to salvage your question.. Good luck

Comment: I hate these sort of questions. If you don't know how to time it yourself then you probably don't need to know or care what the answer is, and if you do know how to time it yourself why are you asking here?

Comment: My recommendation: Do what is more readable to use first and see if it's too slow. If it isn't you're done and have nice readable code. If it is, use a profiler and check what slows it down, it might be something completely different.

Comment: My answer got deleted by a mod (apparently linking to the canonical source instead of redundantly repeating the same info here is not helpful?) so here it is again:  
 

You should read http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/ as it covers this in detail and explains it better than most SO answers will.

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely : thanks alot for your helping i will read it Inshaa'-ALLAH

Answer (score 5):

The difference is negligible in both cases. You shouldn't worry about these issues until you found them to be really issues. Short answer: do the way you like more and consider different aspects like how you will use the returned values later.

If you pass arguments by reference then they're already allocated on stack or dynamically and their pointed values are filled by the function. Time is spent in copying all the pointers to the stack and in storing at their addresses in called function.

In the second case the whole struct is allocated on stack and filled (probably by a single constructor that is missing in your struct). Time is spent in constructing the object onto the stack and in filling its values.

Answer (score -1):

When function returns something bigger than long (on x86 and other 32 bit processors) or long long (on x86_64 and another 64 bit architectures) it returns pointer to alocated memory and then data is being copied to local structure.

```
struct example
{
     long long a,b,c;
};

example create_new_struct(void)
{
     example tmp;           //new object is created
     tmp.a = 3;
     tmp.b = 4;
     bmp.c = 5;
     return example;       //in low-level pointer is returned and all data copied

}

void modify_existing_structure(example & tmp)
{
     tmp.a = 3;           //setting data directly
     tmp.b = 4;
     tmp.c = 5;
     return;
}

int main(void)
{
    example a = create_new_struct(), b;  //varaibles are being copied
    modify_existing_structure(b);        //variables are being set directly
    return 0;
}
```

So you definitly shoud use references. But (as was noticed) your code makes zero sense. You shoud not use anonymous structures and parse all variables separated. In your code you create six pointers instead of one for each function call.

Also, I think you shoud learn more about object-oriented programming.

Comment: Return value optimization means that in most modern compilers the copy you mention is not made at all.

Comment: You should read about [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) before stating _"So you definitly shoud use references"_

Comment: Your answer is incorrect for the following reason: there are two calling major conventions. Unix calling convention allows for return two 64-bit types or one 128-bit type, and Microsoft calling conventions only allows for two 32-bit types or one 64-bit types. The reasoning is how the ALU works, and that the x64 calling convention doesn't fully support 128-bit ALU instructions but can do word * word = dword, but not dword * dword = dword, else it would be a 128-bit processor.